# linking a local windows git repository to the aws linux git server

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, amazon-web-services, git

I want to create a git server on my aws linux server so that whenever I want to update my website in the public_html I dont have to manually transfer files to the server, I want to make use of git, being able to push changes to the remote server from my local machine.

I have successfully created the  a bare git repository and have made a post-receive hook to update the `public_html`. So that, it updates the `public_html` whenever changes are pushed locally. I am now failing to add this repository to my local **Windows Machine**. Since I am using the aws instance, It has to be accessed using the private key key.pem, (that is how access it with putty). I am failing how to add this repository to my local machine in a way also telling git about the private key.

This is what I have done:

```
$> git remote add project_files ssh://ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/~ec2-user/repo
```

After I try to push:

```
git push project_files +master:refs/heads/master
```

This is what I get:

```
$> git push project_files +master:refs/heads/master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I dont seem to be getting around this error.

Comment: "Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."  Are you able to ssh to `ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` successfully?  It sounds like your ssh authentication is not set up properly.

Comment: Try setting the host-specific SSH key using the advice in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5820280